# RefineryCMS - Can't find extensions for installed blog and site search engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines, refinerycms

I have installed three engines: events, blogs, and site search. When I've installed events engine, a compiled file was created under root/vendors/extensions/events. However, I can't find these folders for blogs and site search.

Following is my gem files:

```
  * actionmailer (3.2.16)
  * actionpack (3.2.16)
  * activemodel (3.2.16)
  * activerecord (3.2.16)
  * activeresource (3.2.16)
  * activesupport (3.2.16)
  * acts-as-taggable-on (2.4.1)
  * acts_as_indexed (0.8.3)
  * arel (3.0.3)
  * awesome_nested_set (2.1.6)
  * babosa (0.3.11)
  * bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
  * builder (3.0.4)
  * bundler (1.3.5)
  * coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
  * decorators (1.0.3)
  * devise (2.2.8)
  * dragonfly (0.9.15)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (2.0.2)
  * filters_spam (0.3)
  * friendly_id (4.0.10.1)
  * globalize (3.0.2)
  * hike (1.2.3)
  * i18n (0.6.9)
  * journey (1.0.4)
  * jquery-rails (2.3.0)
  * json (1.8.1)
  * mail (2.5.4)
  * mime-types (1.25.1)
  * multi_json (1.8.2)
  * orm_adapter (0.5.0)
  * paper_trail (2.7.2)
  * polyglot (0.3.3)
  * rack (1.4.5)
  * rack-cache (1.2)
  * rack-ssl (1.3.3)
  * rack-test (0.6.2)
  * rails (3.2.16)
  * rails-i18n (0.7.4)
  * rails_autolink (1.0.9)
  * railties (3.2.16)
  * rake (10.1.0)
  * rdoc (3.12.2)
  * refinerycms (2.1.1)
  * refinerycms-acts-as-indexed (1.0.0)
  * refinerycms-authentication (2.1.1)
  * refinerycms-blog (2.1.0)
  * refinerycms-core (2.1.1)
  * refinerycms-dashboard (2.1.1)
  * refinerycms-events (1.0)
  * refinerycms-i18n (2.1.0)
  * refinerycms-images (2.1.1)
  * refinerycms-pages (2.1.1)
  * refinerycms-resources (2.1.1)
  * refinerycms-search (2.1.0)
  * refinerycms-settings (2.1.1)
  * routing-filter (0.3.1)
  * sass (3.2.12)
  * sass-rails (3.2.6)
  * seo_meta (1.4.0)
  * sprockets (2.2.2)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.8)
  * thor (0.18.1)
  * tilt (1.4.1)
  * treetop (1.4.15)
  * truncate_html (0.9.2)
  * tzinfo (0.3.38)
  * uglifier (2.3.2)
  * warden (1.2.3)
  * will_paginate (3.0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can run `bundle show [gem name]` and it should show you where the gems are located.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, they're tucked away in the gem's own directory, the location of which depends on your OS and ruby management system you're using (rbenv, rvm, etc.)